# How to Solve Brython Giving Error for the code value it got from Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, html, ace-editor, brython

Please check the Images or Image links of my problem!

[When I write my code in Ace Editor like this  then Brython gives the correct result!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue5Ux.png)

[When I extend my code or the div resizes and hides the code like in this case 'pri' of print is hidden because of extending code, it gives an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ersyT.png)

[I have also tried wrapping the text but then also Brython gives an error!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aK4Uw.png)

My Brython and Ace Configurations are as follows!

```js
function run() {
  const console = document.getElementById("console");
  const runner = new BrythonRunner({
    stdout: {
      write(content) {
        console.innerHTML += content;
        console.scrollTop = console.scrollHeight;
      },
      flush() {}
    },
    stderr: {
      write(content) {
        console.innerHTML += content;
        console.scrollTop = console.scrollHeight;
      },
      flush() {}
    },
    stdin: {
      async readline() {
        console.innerHTML += "\n";
        console.scrollTop = console.scrollHeight;
        var userInput = prompt();
        return userInput;
      },
      flush() {}
    }
  });
  var code = editor.getValue();
  runner.runCode(code)
}

function run_init() {

  if (document.getElementById("console") != '') {
    document.getElementById("console").innerHTML = '';
    run();
    console.log(document.getElementById('editor').innerText);


  } else {
    run()
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="run()">run</button>
<div class='editor_class' id='editor'>print('Hello World')</div>
<div class='compiler_class'><textarea id='console' readonly></textarea></div>

<script src="https://ajaxorg.github.io/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githack.com/pythonpad/brython-runner/master/lib/brython-runner.bundle.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script>
  var editor = ace.edit("editor");
  editor.setTheme("ace/theme/vibrant_ink");
  editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/python");
  editor.setFontSize("16px");
  editor.container.style.height = "100px"
  editor.setOptions({
    enableLiveAutocompletion: true,
    copyWithEmptySelection: true,
    showGutter: true,

    useWrapMode: false, // wrap text to view
    indentedSoftWrap: false,
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error was to use innerText on editor container instead of  `editor.getValue();`, i have updated your code snippet and it works now.

Comment: Thanks, You Solved My Biggest Problem!